# how to get the IST from google calendar using google API

Tags: c#, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

In my calendar time shows are in IST
In my application using Google calendar API I am getting time in GMT
How to get events time in IST i.e `GMT+05.30`

[image: Please see this image]

```
                request.TimeMin = dtStart;
                request.TimeMax = dtEnd;
                request.ShowDeleted = false;
                request.SingleEvents = true;
              //  request.TimeZone = "Asia/Calcutta";
```

Answer (score 2):

The Google .net client library appears to be doing some fun stuff with your date.

**Code ripped from the Calendar v3 dll**

Source can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/download/calendar/v3/csharp)

```
/// <summary>The date, in the format "yyyy-mm-dd", if this is an all-day event.</summary>
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute("date")]
        public virtual string Date { get; set; } 

        /// <summary>The time, as a combined date-time value (formatted according to RFC3339). A time zone offset is
        /// required unless a time zone is explicitly specified in timeZone.</summary>
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute("dateTime")]
        public virtual string DateTimeRaw { get; set; }

        /// <summary><seealso cref="System.DateTime"/> representation of <see cref="DateTimeRaw"/>.</summary>
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore]
        public virtual System.Nullable<System.DateTime> DateTime
        {
            get
            {
                return Google.Apis.Util.Utilities.GetDateTimeFromString(DateTimeRaw);
            }
            set
            {
                DateTimeRaw = Google.Apis.Util.Utilities.GetStringFromDateTime(value);
            }
        }
```

**code ripped from core lib [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/1dce119eb5200be57a6ff24159b895594d6bd558/Src/Support/GoogleApis.Core/Apis/Util/Utilities.cs)**

```
 /// <summary>
        /// Parses the input string and returns <see cref="System.DateTime"/> if the input is a valid 
        /// representation of a date. Otherwise it returns <c>null</c>.
        /// </summary>
        public static DateTime? GetDateTimeFromString(string raw)
        {
            DateTime result;
            if (!DateTime.TryParse(raw, out result))
            {
                return null;
            }
            return result;
        }
```

**My Suggestion:**

I suggest you take the raw string datetimeRaw and cast it to a date yourself.  I should probably add an issue to the client lib to add a true date cast to date as well instead of always casting it to local time.

I added a bug / feature request on the client lib [[Calendar V3 generated] date cast to local time but not actual](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/674)

Comment: @DalmTo I have added the image please take a look once. DateTimeRaw is the IST time while DateTime is the GMT. My system date format is GMT. Is it because of system timezone?

Comment: Picture helped I had to go dig around in the source code :)

Comment: Oh and I stole your picture for the issue request I hope that is ok with you.

Comment: Thanks... Please update the link for github in your above comment.

Comment: If you mean the one for calendar that downloads the source file for calendar dll.  There is no GitHub link for that one.   The dlls for the individual APIs is programmatically generated via the Discovery API and a python script.   They aren't on GitHub you have to download them.

Comment: I mean to say  for "[Calendar V3 generated] date cast to local time but not actual"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102451/discussion-between-pritesh-chhunchha-and-daimto).

Comment: ooops fixed that link now